# Php fcputsv with associative/weird structured array

Tags: php, csv

```
Array ( 
    [titel] => dadada 
    [starttime] => 23:59 
    [endtime] => 03:57 
    [startdate] => 2017-01-17  
    [enddate] => 2017-01-20 
    [kategorie] => Array ( [0] => privat ) 
)
```

The above is the output of `print_r` of my array.
Unfortunatly `fcputcsv` returns a string to array or a second element expected to be array.

```
// print_r($eingabe); 
 $fp = fopen('kalender.csv', 'w');
//fputcsv($fp, $eingabe);

fclose($fp);
```

What's the best way to import the contents of that array into my csv file?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `fputcsv()` expects `$eingabe` to not contain any array inside so you need convert any internal array into string  before using `fputcsv()`

```
$eingabe['kategorie']  =  implode("|",$eingabe['kategorie']);
```

I have used `|` symbol to separate values but you can use any string